# write static rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

These are some lines from my htaccess site.

```
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to rewrite a static rule for condition www.xample.com/name to www.xample.com/index.php?route=xyz/abc. For this i came up with this solution but its not working for me.

```
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^name$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=xyz/abc

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was very simple in fact. Anyone who is looking for solution can add this to htaccess

```
RewriteRule name index.php?route=xyz/abc
```